# MSI WIX how to rewrite an Ini File component on change install

Tags: wix, windows-installer

i have an normal component with an ini file.

```
<Feature Id="F.my_ini_feature" Level="1" Display="hidden">
    <ComponentRef Id="C.my_ini"/>
</Feature>

<Component Id="C.my_ini" Guid='my_guid' Directory='PRODUCT_BIN' Feature='Complete' >
  <CreateFolder/>
  <IniFile Id="ConfigFileLocal1" Action="addLine" Directory="PRODUCT_BIN" 
     Name="start.ini" Section="ENVIRONS" 
     Key="MyEnv" Value="[new_var]" />
</Component>
```

the file is create on install and removed on uninstall. But i have to rewrite the file also on a change install because the value of "new_var" is changed. How to force the MSI installer to deploy this component again in change case?

i already try the REINSTALL property like this, which works quite well

```
<SetProperty 
 Sequence="ui" Before="ExecuteAction" 
 Id="REINSTALL" 
 Value="F.my_ini_feature,[REINSTALL]">
 _CHANGE
</SetProperty>
```

but there is one case i can´t figure out. When the user goes to program add/remove and press change and there uninstall. So basically i am still in "CHANGE" and i can´t detect the new state uninstall.

I also try to set the REINSTALL property based on the feature state in the execute sequence but this fails. It seems that this is not possible at all, because MSI will not read the content of REINSTALL again.

```
<SetProperty 
  Sequence="execute" Before="ProcessComponents" 
  Id="REINSTALL" 
  Value="F.make_start_env_local,[REINSTALL]">
   <![CDATA[!F.F.my_ini_feature= 3 AND &F.F.my_ini_feature <> 2]]>  
</SetProperty>
```

Is there any better to force a component reinstall except on a real uninstall ?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

after hours of testing this seems to be the solution. The important points are

- the action must be before "CostInitialize" because than the MSI will work correct
- the app/remove/change workflow also works with this code because the REINSTALL property is removed automatically bei MSI

  ```
  <SetProperty
    Action="PreSetReInstall"        
    Sequence="ui" Before="CostInitialize" Secure="true"
    Id="REINSTALL" 
    Value="F.my_ini_feature">
    _CHANGE
   </SetProperty>
  ```